# compare string obtained via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery:

```
    $.get(URL, function(data){

            if(data == 'no_credits'){
                alert("no credits");
                return;
            }
            else{
                // WHY HERE>?!
            }
```

and my problem is that url return 'no_credits' but code goes to `else` block code, please help!

EDIT : `alert(data);` prints no_credits

Comment: Maybe you have trailing/leading white spaces in `data`? How do you verify that `data` only contains `no_credits` ?

Comment: Try adding the 'text' argument to your $.get function

Answer (score 3):

You probably have trailing spaces or capitalization differences.

Try

```
if($.trim(data).toLowerCase() === 'no_credits'){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get(URL,function(data){...},'text');
```

Your function is outside the $.get function, so of course it doesn't get the server's response as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dumping the data object ? do a `console.log(data);` in Firefox (with installed firebug) and check the firebug console. I think the data is not the output of the server but a response object.

Answer (score -1):

to send data to front end from backend code....make sure u r not using any function which adds something by itself...like println() function of Java Streams adds one "\n" at the end of string and then sends..use print() function instead...

Comment: Could you clean up your post some?